# Avoid reprocessing previously processed messages

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When processing emails in an Outlook mailbox, is it possible to use some kind of ID to record the last message processed avoiding the need to iterate through all messages every time?

I'm trying to strip attachments to free up mailbox space. I don't want to iterate every message in a mail folder each time the code runs. I could use the mail folder name and the message date, but what happens if a folder is renamed, or messages moved?

I was hoping there was some kind of message ID I could use but can see neither the MAPI ID nor the Outlook Mail ID being suitable here.

Comment: Could you use a folder called "To be processed" then run through those messages, and when you're done with them, move those messages to "Inbox"?

Comment: Maybe MailItem.EntryID?  But "The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866458%28v=office.15%29.aspx), but may not affect you.

Comment: Joseph, not really as other co-workers will also want to use this tool, and the idea is to create a windows folder structure mirroring the outlook mailbox structure.  VBlades, I had looked at the EntryID but as you say it changes, and that would impact so unfortunately it wouldn't be suitable.  It's looking like I will have to record folder name and date/time and use that as the basis with a caveat that any messages moved from one folder to another may get missed on occasion.  Thanks for the suggestions anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid reprocessing previously processed emails, you have no recourse but to either record the email's unique identifiers externally for later checking, or flagging emails with a specific value (such as adding a Category, setting a flag, adding a custom field, setting an internal field, etc.) to avoid processing them later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Eric.  My issue isn't so much with the actual processing, but I was hoping not to have to iterate through emails which have already ben checked for attachments.  It is this that I can't find a way round.  If a mail folder has 1000 emails, then on first pass, all 1000 mails need to be inspected to check for an attachment and 'processed' if attchment(s) exist.  If by the following week 10 additional emails have 'landed' in that folder, I was hoping to be able to identify those 10 without the need to iterate through the previously insected 1000.

Comment: In that case you can filter out the older or newer emails by ReceivedDate with Items.Restrict

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Eric.  That sounds like what I was looking for.